# Why won't my hg work?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to do hg pull from another computer but hg is not giving me the latest version. It might be that I'm on the wrong branch. What can I do to resolve the error? When I make hg diff there is no diff but I know that is is not the latest version.

Comment: Have you remembered to update your working copy? If you just pulled, your repository will have received any new changesets from the source of the pull, but unless you update your working copy it will not change. Can you please verify the steps you did, messages and error messages you received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg diff` will never show you any output irrespective of the currently changeset, assuming that you have no uncommitted changes.

`hg pull` does not update your working dir to any revision - it just pulls the changesets into your mercurial repository without updating your currently checked our revision

You'll need to update your working copy to whatever revision you want. If there is only one branch involved, a simple `hg update` will do the trick. If there are several branches involved and the new changesets are on another branch, you'll need to tell mercurial explicitly that you're also ok with a branch change during update: `hg update --check`. Alternatively you can also try `hg update --rev tip` after the pull. If there's no branch switch involved and necessary, you can also tell pull to update immediately after a successful pull (but it won't switch branches): `hg pull --update`